# Print a .svg document without a black background on imported image

Tags: gimp, inkscape, transparency

I am using GIMP 2.8.10 and inkscape 0.91 on Windows.  I want to:

1. Manipulate a photo in GIMP's .xcf format by removing the background -- it should be transparent.
2. Export the image in .png format.
3. Import the .png into an Inkscape .svg document.  Thanks to transparency, I should be able to see the lines in the layer beneath, *unlike* this screen shot where the white background blocks them:

[image]

5. Print the .svg document **with the background transparent instead of black.**

Right now, if I print what is above but with a transparent background for the picture, I get a black square with a tree on it.

In this particular case, I can use a white background for the picture and simply put that layer beneath the one with the lines.  But this will be inadequate as complexity increases.

I've tried a dozen permutations for both GIMP export (alpha channel for layer, .png export settings such as transparent pixels, etc.) and Inkscape import and preferences (alpha background color).

I could export from Inkscape to .png, but surely that isn't necessary.

Can you describe a successful trip from GIMP to Inkscape, step-by-step?

---

Update:

I ran across posts that discuss layer opacity in Inkscape and also a [recognized bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1418865).  I decided to export to .png for my printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Ensure every object](http://forum.inkscapecommunity.com/index.php?topic=221.0) has zero transparency.  Make all layers visible and unlocked, "Select All in All Layers", go to the Fill and Stroke panel and set the Opacity slider to 100%.
2. Other points that may apply:  Page background color in Document Properties (set to white) and transparency for each layer (set to 100% opaque).  I've wasted too much printer ink already to want to check whether these are critical.
3. Inserting bitmap images may cause a problem.

---

A [known](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1418865/comments/4) [bug](http://forum.inkscapecommunity.com/index.php?topic=274.0) when using the 64-bit version of Inkscape on a 64-bit Windows OS may be the culprit.  Simply replace with the 32-bit version.